# Compiling Love 2D Xcode : Undefined Symbols for Architecture

Tags: c++, xcode, love2d, lua-api

How do i get these "symbols" recognized by the compiler when i compile c++ in xcode. here's the errors ( i have a feeling that its ignoring the frameworks then giving errors for missing frameworks)

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/Library/Frameworks/IL.framework/IL, missing required architecture x86_64 in file
ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/Library/Frameworks/Vorbis.framework/Vorbis, missing required architecture x86_64 in file
ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/Library/Frameworks/FreeType.framework/FreeType, missing required architecture x86_64 in file
ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/Library/Frameworks/Lua.framework/Lua, missing required architecture x86_64 in file
ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/Library/Frameworks/Ogg.framework/Ogg, missing required architecture x86_64 in file
ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/Library/Frameworks/physfs.framework/physfs, missing required architecture x86_64 in file
ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/Library/Frameworks/libmodplug.framework/libmodplug, missing required architecture x86_64 in file
ld: warning: ignoring file /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk/Library/Frameworks/mpg123.framework/mpg123, missing required architecture x86_64 in file
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_luaL_newstate", referenced from:
      _SDL_main in love-33750B9883D2854D.o
      love::thread::Thread::ThreadThread::SDL_main() in Thread.o
  "_luaL_openlibs", referenced from:
      _SDL_main in love-33750B9883D2854D.o
      love::thread::Thread::ThreadThread::SDL_main() in Thread.o
  "_lua_createtable", referenced from:
      _SDL_main in love-33750B9883D2854D.o
      love::luax_register_module(lua_State*, love::WrappedModule const&) in runtime.o
      love::luax_insistglobal(lua_State*, char const*) in runtime.o
      love::luax_insist(lua_State*, int, char const*) in runtime.o
      _auxiliar_newclass in auxiliar.o
      _global_select in select.o
      _make_assoc in select.o
      ...
  "_lua_pushstring", referenced from:
      _SDL_main in love-33750B9883D2854D.o
      love::luax_register_type(lua_State*, char const*, luaL_Reg const*) in runtime.o
      _auxiliar_newclass in auxiliar.o
      _auxiliar_tostring in auxiliar.o
      _auxiliar_add2group in auxiliar.o
      _auxiliar_getgroupudata in auxiliar.o
      _global_create in tcp.o
      ...
  "_lua_rawseti", referenced from:
      _SDL_main in love-33750B9883D2854D.o
      love::luax_table_insert(lua_State*, int, int, int) in runtime.o
      love::physics::box2d::Body::getFixtureList(lua_State*) const in Body-3A4BFE6EB3B8CF74.o
      love::physics::box2d::World::getBodyList(lua_State*) const in World.o
      love::physics::box2d::World::getJointList(lua_State*) const in World.o
      love::physics::box2d::World::getContactList(lua_State*) const in World.o
      _luaopen_love in love-9091511F51D4A764.o
      ...
```

(And it goes on and on; the errors are similar so i just sampled)

Comment: Looks a bit odd; why do you have `Lua`, `Ogg`, etc within your SDK?  I don't have them within my OSX 10.7 SDK.

Comment: because they are dependancies of love2d , i just imported them to the project

Comment: And it (XCode?) moved the frameworks into the SDK?

Comment: Well they should be installed somewhere else so they aren't lost during an update.  They also look like the wrong architecture so who/whatever put them there did it wrong.

Comment: Yes, the linker seems to believe that the libraries are not compiled for 64-bit mode, but the main programs is.

Comment: yes this is a weird error, i fixed 140 errors by reimporting the frameworks that are being copied to the application because it stated that they were coming from "~/Library" when i dont have them there

Comment: it has Mach-O-Linker error if that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue:

There were broken references to the frameworks that were imported ( meaning the frameworks weren't in the place xcode thought they were) and i just deleted that and relinked them and everything compiled fine